# Attaching a file with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails, poltergeist

I'm having issues attaching a file with capybara.

I have a client model

```
class Client
  mount_uploader :logo, ClientUploader
  validates :name, :logo, presence: true
end
```

In my view I have the form seperated into tabs, the logo is on the media tab and it's switched by javascript so I'm using the poltergeist javascript driver.

```
it "should allow a client to be created", js: true do
  click_link "New Client"
  fill_in "Name", with: "My Client"
  click_link "Media"
  attach_file("client_logo", File.join(Rails.root, "spec/support/images/landscape_image.jpg"))
  click_button "Create Client"
  expect(page).to have_content("Client was successfully created.")
end
```

The controller

```
class ClientsController
  def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)
    if @client.save
      redirect_to clients_url, notice: 'Client was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:name, :logo, :remote_logo_url, :logo_cache, :website, :display)
  end
end
```

I've used launchy `save_and_open_page` and it gets to the correct tab, so the field is there (capybara would complain if it wasn't) and the image path is correct (again, capybara complains if it's not).  Yet I get the following error:

```
1) Creating A Client should allow a client to be created
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content("Client was successfully created.")
       expected to find text "Client was successfully created." in "MANAGE YOUR CONTENT Clients Site Navigation Site Navigation Stored Images Stored Documents Site Settings View Website Manage Administrators Logout New Client SEE ALL CLIENTS 1 error prohibited this client from being saved: Logo can't be blank ContentMediaSettings Name Website Site Structure Stored Documents Stored Images"
```

I'm stumped, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What version of phantomjs are you using with poltergeist?

Comment: 2.0.1-development, I just went to phantomjs site and downloaded the one linked on home.  Thanks, didn't even consider it could be the issue but I see it's a known issue with 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File uploading doesn't work in poltergeist when used with PhantomJS 2.0.0. It's fixed in 2.0.1 (if it's ever released). If you are using 2.0.0 you have a couple of choices, revert to 1.9.8,  build your own copy of 2.0.1, or swap to using selenium or capybara-WebKit for these tests

Comment: Thanks, so much. I didn't even consider phantomjs could be the issue